# How to enable @Secured annotation on my Controllers using spring-security-pac4j 2.0

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, cas, jasig

I coded the integration of my [web application](https://github.com/wbsouza/demo-spring-cas-pac4j) using spring-security with pac4j and CAS based on [spring-security-pac4j-demo](https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-pac4j-demo) with the following dependencies :

```
compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-core:1.8.8"
compile "org.pac4j:pac4j-cas:1.8.8"
compile "org.pac4j:spring-security-pac4j:1.4.3"
compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.1.0.RELEASE"
```

However, when I tried to upgrade to **version 2.0.0** of the **spring-security-pac4j** I realized the approach was completely changed. Before I used to load the user roles in my customized class UserDetailService:

```java
@Component("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsService implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<ClientAuthenticationToken>  {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsService.class);

    @Inject
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserDetails(ClientAuthenticationToken token) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        String username = token.getUserProfile().getId().toLowerCase();
        log.debug("Authenticating {}", username);

        Optional<User> userFromDatabase = userRepository.findOneByUsername(username);
        if (!userFromDatabase.isPresent()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + username + " was not found in the database");
        } else if (!userFromDatabase.get().getActivated()) {
            throw new UserNotActivatedException("User " + username + " was not activated");
        }

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Authority authority : userFromDatabase.get().getAuthorities()) {
            GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName());
            grantedAuthorities.add(grantedAuthority);
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username,username, grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

And with some extra configurations the spring-security was working to check the user roles access on my Controllers annotated with @Secured.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/app/*")
public class SecureController {

    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    @RequestMapping("/secure/admins")
    public String admins(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("roleName", "ROLE_ADMIN");
        return "secure";
    }

    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    @RequestMapping("/secure/users")
    public String users(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("roleName", "ROLE_USER");
        return "secure";
    }
}
```

With the **version 2.0.0** of **spring-security-pac4j**, even looking in the demos I still I have no idea where to start in order to make updated my project with the new version of pac4j and keep it working with the **@Secured** annotation. If anyone can help with any tips and/or directions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of pac4j and spring-security-pac4j.

Yes, the version 2.0 is really different, but this was necessary to benefit from all pac4j features.

After a successful CAS authentication, a `CasProfile` is created and saved in your security context (in the `Pac4jAuthentication` token). To compute specific roles for your profile (by fetching them from the database for example), you need to create a new [`AuthorizationGenerator`](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/master/pac4j-core/src/main/java/org/pac4j/core/authorization/generator/AuthorizationGenerator.java)  and attach it to the client: `casClient.addAuthorizationGenerator(myAuthGenerator);`

Comment: I tried to migrate the project to the new version based on the sample and the information you gave me, but I'm getting an error of many redirects in the browser. I am may missing something because the sample uses xml and I'm using an annotated with @Configuration class approach.

Comment: Can you post your stack trace and detailed error on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/pac4j-users?

Comment: sure, I'm going to create a branch on github and also mak a post post on he pac4-users forum. Thanks again